Create new count with \def
I have the following macro/command:
\def\definenewcounter#1{\newcount \csname#1\endcsname}

It is supposed to create a new count with it's name being whatever argument 1 is, but it is throwing errors. How can this be resolved?
Here is a fuller example:
\documentclass[]{article}

\def\definenewcounter#1{\newcount \csname#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\definenewcounter{countertest}
\end{document}


@DavidCarlisle that's not fair, the last question was using \advance which would scan for a number and hence auto-expand the \csname, whereas \newcount just takes the first token, which makes the \expandafter necessary.

The code shown defines \csname to be a count register, and then will produce multiple errors.
You could use
\documentclass[]{article}

\def\definenewcounter#1{\expandafter\newcount \csname#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\definenewcounter{countertest}
\end{document}

But that seems a strange construct for LaTeX which already provides
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{countertest}
\end{document}

